# Using add_rvalue_reference and add_lvalue_reference with template types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compiler-errors, is-same

My small test program is aimed at testing the use of `add_rvalue_reference` and `add_lvalue_reference` for obtaining references of template types.

//test.h

```
#include<cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

using std::size_t;
using std::add_lvalue_reference;
using std::add_rvalue_reference;

template<class T>
  struct unref {typedef T type;};
template<class T> 
  struct unref<T&>{typedef T type;};
template<class T> 
  struct unref<T&&>{typedef T type;};

template<typename T>
class A{
   public:
   constexpr A(T);
   constexpr ~A();
   private:
   A()=delete; 
   A(const A&)=delete;
   A& operator=(const A&)=delete;
   private:
   T elem;
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
using arrayofAs = A<T>[N];

template<typename T, size_t N>
using lvrefarrayofAs = add_lvalue_reference<arrayofAs<T>>;

template<typename T, size_t N>
using rvrefarrayofAs = add_rvalue_reference<arrayofAs<T>>;

template<typename T> constexpr A<T>::A(T elem):elem(elem){}
template<typename T> constexpr A<T>::~A(){}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::is_same;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (){

  cout << is_same<unref<lvrefarrayofAs>, arrayofAs>::value << endl;  
  cout << is_same<unref<rvrefarrayofAs>, arrayofAs>::value << endl;  

  return 0;
}
```

To begin with, I get the following compilation error in `test.h`:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
test.h:35:55: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
   35 | using lvrefarrayofAs = add_lvalue_reference<arrayofAs<T>>;
      |                                                       ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

My understanding is that the template array size is not part of its type (please correct me if I am mistaken on this), so not sure why the compiler insists on specifying the template non-type paramter?

The error disappears after I rewrite the two related `using` declarations in the original code as shown below:

```
    template<typename T, size_t N>
    using lvrefarrayofAs = add_lvalue_reference<arrayofAs<T,N>>;
    
    template<typename T, size_t N>
    using rvrefarrayofAs = add_rvalue_reference<arrayofAs<T,N>>;
```

But now I get the following error in main.c:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:21:39: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list 
for ‘template<class T> struct unref’
   21 |   cout << is_same<unref<lvrefarrayofAs>, arrayofAs>::value << endl;
      |                                       ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

I presume the type of argument 1 passed to `is_same<>` template is valid, based on the `using` declarations for both `unref<T&>`and `lvrefarrayofAs` in `test.h`.

So why does the compiler report this error?

TIA

Comment: There seems to be some very basic misunderstanding here. `lvrefarrayofAs` is not a type, `lvrefarrayofAs<int, 42>` would be a type. It's also unclear what you expected `arrayofAs<T>` to do. `arrayofAs<int, 42>` is `A<int>[42]`, but what `arrayofAs<int>` would be?

Comment: You probably want `std::is_same<unref<lvrefarrayofAs<int, 42>>::type, arrayofAs<int, 42>>::value`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for pointing out the flaw in my understanding...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
cout << is_same<unref<lvrefarrayofAs>, arrayofAs>::value << endl;
                                    ^           ^
```

Here you need to specify the `T` and the `N`

```
lvrefarrayofAs<int, 4>::type
```

Note that you need the `::type` there, unless you change `add_lvalue_reference` -> `std::add_lvalue_reference_t` (same for rvalue)

You want the `type` from `unref`:

```
unref<lvrefarrayofAs<int, 4>::type>::type
```

The expression then becomes

```
is_same<unref<lvrefarrayofAs<int, 4>::type>::type, arrayofAs<int, 4>>::value
```

Or

```
is_same_v<unref<lvrefarrayofAs<int, 4>::type>::type, arrayofAs<int, 4>>
```